# Android EditText.setError() yields invisible error text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a very simple EditText, as follows:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/myedit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:maxLength="32"/>
```

In some validation code, I use Android's `EditText.setError()` to show any validation errors. This works fine in OS 2.x but not on an OS 3.x device (Xoom) -- on the Xoom you can see the outline of the error popup but you cannot see the error text.

I'm guessing that the text is there, but it is invisible. How do I make it visible? I don't see an `android:textColor` that would relate to error text.

Also, if the text is indeed invisible, then any ideas why 2.x behaves differently to 3.x -- seems like this would cause backward-compatibility problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the text is there, but it's light gray on a white background because the activity is using Theme.Light.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It looks like you can work around this problem by calling EditText.setError() with a SpannableStringBuilder object rather than a String.

```
int ecolor = xxxx; // whatever color you want
String estring = "Input is incorrect";
ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);
myedittext.setError(ssbuilder);
```

Comment: Standard Android Color class, for example Color.YELLOW or Color.argb(127, 255, 0, 255).  See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html for details.

Comment: A hack, but it works if you choose a color that overlays well with white or black.

Answer (score 18):

For a more elegant solution try this one:

```
editText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Error Message!</font>"));
```

Comment: but  I try this not work,
edtAddr.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#898989'>Error Message!</font>"));

Answer (score 6):

Use native [parent theme](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) for appropriate API level in your own customized style!  "@android:style/theme.name".

Distinguish themes by [Configuration qualifier](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources):

```
value/style.xml - > parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"
value-v11/style.xml -> parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
value-v14/style.xml -> parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"
```

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22920

Comment: Thanks, I used the solution given by the link : <style name="MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    </style>

Comment: This solution works for me since accepted solution always use black (fixed) color

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case, I had applied the parent="android:Theme.Light" to values-V14/styles.xml. This made the EditText control to look like a control from android API 2.3.3 and below. But the error message text was all white and hence, was not visible. After some head scratching I figured this out.

Change the parent="android:Theme.Light" to parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" (what ever Holo theme). But in the EditText definition add `android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"`

My EditText looks like this

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                style="@style/editTextNormal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/email"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text" />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the text color of the error text view, then  you should add this code in your theme files.

For v8:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/secondary_text_light</item>
```

For v11:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
```