# edittext validation

Tags: java, android

I have following small block of code to set validation on edit text when a button is pressed and display the validation message in a dialog.

**Java Code**

```
setContentView(R.layout.addnewcontacts);
            Button buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
            final EditText editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (editTextName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        editTextName.setError( "First name is required!" );

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Code is working fine but the popup is not displaying text in it.

**Screen shot :**

[image]

Why popup is not showing text?

Comment: maybe the text is white

Comment: How can i set text color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `EditText.setError()` with a `SpannableStringBuilder` object.

Check this previous SO question: [Android EditText.setError() yields invisible error text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273932/android-edittext-seterror-yields-invisible-error-text)

Answer (score 0):

Use [EditText.setTextColor(int color)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29) to set the required color for the text element.

Answer (score 0):

Just add edittext color into your xml file.

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple just follow the below code it is working fine.

```
final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(et.getText().toString().length()==0){
                et.setError("it is wrong");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the theme you have applied .Use basic theme to check error text