# Android setError() remains blank

Tags: android, validation

I have these few lines of code to validate form input. However, it doesn't output anything - just a blank box. What am I missing, please?

```
 public void onClick(View view)
 {
    if( view.getId() == R.id.btnLogin )
    {
        TestClass.setUsername( txtUserName.getEditableText().toString() );
        TestClass.setPassword( txtPassword.getEditableText().toString() );

        if( TestClass.getUsername().toString().length() == 0 )
        {
            this.txtUserName.setError( "Incorrect input!" );
        }
        else if( TestClass.getPassword().toString().length() == 0 )
        {
         this.txtPassword.setError( "Incorrect input!" );
        }
        else
        {
               // do the login stuff here
        }
     } 
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [edittext.setError() not working in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747268/edittext-seterror-not-working-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android EditText.setError() yields invisible error text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273932/android-edittext-seterror-yields-invisible-error-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
int ecolor = Color.RED; // whatever color you want
String estring = "Input is incorrect";  // your error message
ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);
myedittext.setError(ssbuilder);
```

Source: [Android EditText.setError() yields invisible error text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273932/android-edittext-seterror-yields-invisible-error-text)

Answer (score 1):

Use Html object for easy and quick formatting:

```
this.txtUserName.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Incorrect input!</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
               if (editTextName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    int ecolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue); // whatever color you want
                    String estring = "Input is incorrect";
                    ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
                    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
                    ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);
                    editTextName.setError( builder );

                }
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I did a search before posting - but probably not detailed enough.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the application theme in my project "manifest file and error text is appearing now.

before change:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

after change:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```