# CoordinatorLayout messing up setError popup position

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm facing an issue with `EditText` `setError` popup position.

[image: Edit Text Error]

I'm using the following code in to create the layout:

**activity_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/profile" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**profile.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_profile">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etProfileName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:hint="@string/et_hint_profile_name"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**What I have tried**

If I change the `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` with `LinearLayout` the `setError` issue won't happen, but that will change the status bar color to white one and my UI is looking odd.

[image: Corrected, status bar issue]

I'm new to Android programming and not sure what's going on, please help me.

Comment: Try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: @AbhishekV: I tried, that time both error occurs (Popup issue and status bar white color issue)

Comment: I have the same issue and I reported the bug here
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list
bug #193793
feel free to add comments!

Comment: @DSoldo: Thanks for the comment. I voted for your post there and added a comment too. I hope that issue will be fixed soon :)

Comment: @downvoter: What is the reason for down vote ?

Comment: got the same error. the larger the toolbar is, the more shitty it looks... still no solution on this?

Comment: @Anthea: Not yet. I'm watching the above linked google issue ticket. From the status of that issue, I think they are still working on the bug

Comment: I got the same error. Please star the issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193793 so Google takes action.

Comment: @RacZo: Thanks for the comment. I'm the first one stared and commented on that issue you mentioned in above link. Hope google will fix that soon :)

Comment: Today Google finally updated the support design library to v 23.2.0
Now the bug should be fixed!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is an extra LinearLayout in *activity_main.xml* (yes, there):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.biptest.MainActivity">

    <!-- *** THIS ONE *** -->
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" /> <!-- FRAGMENT(S) INSIDE -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- *** BUT LEAVE THE FAB ALONE *** -->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This also works around the layout bug that shows when you toggle visibility of a view in a fragment.

And the next problem is white-on-white error messages in the popup on Android 2.x ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20654838/755804))

Comment: i think everyone can use it, while new build wil be on production

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Testing a little bit the UI, I found that the problem appeared when the EditText widget gets the focus programatically to show the error, in my case calling `.requestFocus()`, but when focusing on the widget again manually the popup appeared correctly.

So my workaround was to delay the call to `.requestFocus()` in a Runnable (simulating a user clicking on the EditText widget).

Here is the code:

```
        if (mFocusView != null) mFocusView.clearFocus(); // clear current focus. Needed to simulate a new "manual" focus

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final boolean b = handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mFocusView.requestFocus(); // request focus
                    }
                }, 1); // only delay 1 milisecond
            }
        });
```

`mFocusView` is the current EditText view to show an error.

Depending on your use case you may need to handle the focus when the keyboard is dismissed, as it makes the popup appear in the wrong position again.

Don't know if this will solve your problem. Hope it helps while Google solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was an Android bug and it is now fixed.

Reference : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193793

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is not the `CoordinatorLayout`, but `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`. As a simple workaround you can remove  the line `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` and add `android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"` to your nested view if you don't need nested scroll.